# Raspberry Pi: File copy to Seagate Backup Plus Bit Errors

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, usb-drive

I have a Raspberry Pi connected to a Seagate Backup Plus 3T external hard drive.
I've written a Python script to make backup copies of files from my Windows File Server onto the external hard drive.

Everything SEEMS to be running fine.  But when I copy a file from the external hard drive back to the Windows File Server, I have random bit errors... specifically the high order bit of random bytes will be a '1' in the copied file (i.e. 0x31 ==> 0xB1, 0x2B ==> 0xAB, 0x71 ==> 0xF1).

In a 9MB .MOV file, I've got 13 of these random bit errors.

In the python application, I've used both shutil.copy2 function to copy the files, and I've written a subroutine to open files for binary read/write and copy 1MB at a time.

When I connected the external hard drive to a Windows 10 machine and tried to copy files from File Server to external hard drive and back, I didn't get any errors.

Comment: And the question is...? Please show a minimal complete verifiable subset of your code. Google mcve if you need guidance on this. And think about what else you could do to diagnose the source of/reason for the not-so-random errors.

Comment: So you would like us to tell you if there's anything wrong with a Python script we can't see?

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with the python script, especially since I'm getting the same results using two different methods.

What I'm trying to determine is whether is the breakdown.  I can't believe I'm the only person to experience this kind of issue.

Comment: So what do YOU think is wrong, then? Tell us. BTW the most common single point of failure in software projects is... software, i.e. you the programmer. Here’s a debugging hint, can you use the OS cp command to reliably copy data to the USB drive?

Comment: Finally got around to testing the file copy with the Pi OS.  Same results.  Random errors and always the high bit.

Comment: After some more trial and error, I've narrowed the problem down to the Pi reading files from my windows network shared drive.  If the source file is on the Pi or the USB drive connected to the Pi, it doesn't matter the destination, the files always match.  But if the source is on the Windows Network Share drive mounted by the Pi, the read generates the random high bit errors.

Comment: BTW, the Windows Network Drive is formatted NTFS and mounted by fstab with the following: //Server/Share /mnt/Server_Share cifs user=user,password=password,uid=pi,gid=pi,x-systemd.automount 0 0

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it figured out.  After additional trial and error, I figured out that there is something wrong with the wired network port on the Pi.  Everything works fine if I swap out my Pi3 with my Pi1, and the Pi3 works if I use the WiFi (been using wired port for speed).